# A detail in the proof of Central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For the sake of completeness i will give the whole theorem:

Let $X_1,X_2...$ be i.i.d random variables with finite expectation and finite $\sigma^2$, and set $S_n = X_1 + X_2+....+X_n \enspace, n \geq 1$, Then :

$\dfrac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

here is the start of the proof:

...It suffices to prove that $\varphi_{\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}}(t) \rightarrow e^{-t^2/2}$.

the relation:

$\dfrac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big(\frac{x_k -\mu}{\sigma} \Big)}{\sqrt{n}} \qquad \boldsymbol{(1)}$

shows that  it is no restriction to assume throughout the proof that $\mu =0$ and $\sigma =1$

Ok. So the question is about the last statement; How does the relation $(1)$ show that we can assume throughout the proof that $\mu = 0 ,\enspace \sigma =1$

Answer (score 4):

The point is that  $Z_k = (X_k - \mu)/\sigma$ are iid with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$, and $\dfrac{S_n - n \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} = \dfrac{\widetilde{S}_n - 0}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $\widetilde{S}_n = \sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$, so it suffices to prove the theorem for the sequence $Z_k$, which is the same as assuming $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$.

Comment: but $X_k$ are not assumed to be normally distr. how can you normalize them is such way. What am I missing @Robert Israel

Comment: I didn't assume they are normal.  The $Z_k$ aren't normal either.  All we know about them is that they are iid with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$ (which just follows from $E[aX+b] = a E[X] + b$ and $\text{Var}(aX+b) = a^2 \text{Var}(X)$).